# Katalon Test Execution

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, execution, katalon-studio

I have a test case created in Katalon to perform a particular action. But I already have a Browser open logged into the website where I wanna execute the test case. Is it possible to possible to use that window and resume my execution for the test case without writing a test case to login?

Answer (score 0):

I would also like it if this possibility existed: to attach to an existing session or switch between sessions, but it can't be done using native Katalon commands.

It is an issue that was proposed to Selenium team (and Katalon is based on Selenium) but was rejected as ["not feasible"](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/18) as that is a "browser-specific feature". It might be possible on IE though.